# ¿Problema al realizar una condicion en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

hola  tengo 3 tablas :

1. tbl_personal_empleado (USUARIOS ACTIVOS)
2. backuppersonal_empleado (USUARIOS INACTIVOS)
3. tbl_login

la tabla **tbl_personal_empleado** contiene 2 triggers

1. backup_empleados
2. usuario_after_insert

el tigger **backup_empleado** se encarga de de que cuando se elimine un usuario de la tabla este lo inserte en la tabla **backuppersonal_empleado** basicamente crea una copia, funciona perfectamente.

el trigger **usuario_after_insert** se encarga que al momento de que se inserte un nuevo usuario este le va a crear un login en la tabla **tbl_login** con una contraseña aleatorio de 6 digitos para que pueda iniciar sesión el trigger es asi

```
CREATE TRIGGER `usuario_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON                                                                
`tbl_personal_empleado`                                                   
FOR EACH ROW                                                                         
BEGIN                                                               
DECLARE id int(11);                                                                
DECLARE usuario varchar(60);                                                        
DECLARE contrasena varchar(40);                                                                                                                                                               
SET id =(NEW.idpersonal_E);                                                           
SET usuario =(NEW.correo_E);                                                                                           
SET contrasena =(SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6) AS                                                                
myrandomstring);

INSERT INTO tbl_login(usuario,contrasena,idpersonal_E) VALUES                                                                                    
(usuario,contrasena,id);

END
```

ahora la tabla **backuppersonal_empleado** contiene otro trigger que se encarga de que cuando sea eliminado el usuario este lo inserte en la table **tbl_personal_empleado** .

la table **tbl_login**  no contiene triggers ni relaciones su estrutura es asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que cuando se habilita un usuario que ya estaba eliminado(DESHABILITADO),la tbl_personal_empleado ejecuta el disparador para crear un nuevo login al  usuario que se esta insertando por lo que al final me queda algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el mismo usuario pero con contraseña nueva, entonces se me ocurrió hacer que el trigger hiciera una validación antes de que si el usuario ya esta insertado en la tbl_login no lo inserte un nuevo login intente esto

```
CREATE TRIGGER `usuario_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON                                                                                                                                            
`tbl_personal_empleado`                                                   
FOR EACH ROW                                                                         
BEGIN

DECLARE id int(11);

DECLARE usuario varchar(60);

DECLARE contrasena varchar(40);

DECLARE idveri int(11);

SET idveri = SELECT idpersonal_E FROM tbl_login;

SET id =(NEW.idpersonal_E);

SET usuario =(NEW.correo_E);

IF id = idveri THEN

SET contrasena =(SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6) AS                                                                
myrandomstring);

INSERT INTO tbl_login(usuario,contrasena,idpersonal_E) VALUES                                                                                    
(usuario,contrasena,id);

ELSE 

END IF;
```

pero me saca el siguiente error

MySQL ha dicho: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SELECT idpersonal_E FROM tbl_login; SET id =(NEW.idpersonal_E); SET usua' en la linea 6

y ya no se que mas pueda hacer

Comment: No hagas una eliminación fisica. Haz una logica. En vez de mandar a otra tabla los usuarios "eliminados" colocale un estado al usuario. Ejemplo: Activo = 1, Inactivo = 2 y te ahorras un trigger. Si el usuario cambia a inactivo solo cambias el estao y ya

Comment: podrias explicarnos mas o menos en que consiste aquello que deseas hacer? ya que con la misma tabla `tbl_personal_empleado` podrias solo agregarle `columna` llamada `status`  que sera 1 si esta activo y 0 si no lo esta. y utilizar esta logica en tu app con ello no eliminarias nunca `usuarios` ya que si `status` es 0 no podra iniciar session y como nunca lo borras no es necesario la tabla `backuppersonal_empleado`!

Comment: El problema puede ser un poco el diseño.
Al insertar en históricos normalmente las llaves originales se cambian por una secuencia automática y timestamp de registro. así no te preocupas de duplicados.
por otro lado, al eliminar un usuario en la tabla principal, puedes considerar borrarlo también en la tabla login, a través de otro trigger, así no se repetirá cuando lo rehabilites, insertándolo de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Después de estar realizando los cambios que me sugirieron en los comentarios se logro arreglar el error del trigger

dejandome como resultado lo siguiente

```
BEGIN

DECLARE id int(11);

DECLARE usuario varchar(60);

DECLARE contrasena varchar(40);

DECLARE idveri int(11);

SET id =(NEW.idpersonal_E);

SET idveri = (SELECT idpersonal_E FROM tbl_login WHERE idpersonal_E = id);

SET usuario =(NEW.correo_E);

IF idveri IS NULL THEN

SET contrasena =(SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6) AS                                                                
myrandomstring);

INSERT INTO tbl_login(usuario,contrasena,idpersonal_E) 
VALUES (usuario,contrasena,id);

END IF;

END
```

Ya lo comprobe y funciona perfectamente sus principales errores fueron

**Linea 7**

la consulta iba entre paréntesis

y por ultimo se agrego un **END** mas y se elimino el **ELSE** vacio